# Glassfish does not process java

Tags: java, ubuntu, glassfish

I have the following issue with my glassfish server:

I have deployed a simple application to the server. The server correctly receives the application as in a web archive. When i open the according website in my browser, the HTML and CSS is displayed properly, but the content's of the expression language are just empty. Furthermore it seems like the java code is not even executed, since i can't see an output of system.out's.

The application itself works perfectly fine on a local glassfish server.

Attached is the source and the web.xml.

**Controller class:**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class CarController implements Serializable {

    String test = "hallo";

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }
}
```

**index.xhtml:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>     
        #{carController.test}
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

- Glassfish version: 4
- Java version: "1.7.0_65" (java installation works with any non glassfish applications)
- Ubuntu version: 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the issue is solved.

Our application consists out of 4 projects. The problem was, that one project had the target java version 8 while on the server is only 7 installed.